# How can I assign a value to x according to y

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have this code that is very annoying to write but does the job, I was wondering if there was a function or class of some sort to help me.

Here's my function:

```
func add_health():
    if wave in range(10,20):
        enemy_health = 2
    elif wave in range(20,30):
        enemy_health = 3.5
    elif wave in range(30,40):
        enemy_health = 5
    elif wave in range(40,50):
        enemy_health = 6.5
    elif wave in range(50,59):
        enemy_health = 8
    elif wave in range(60,69):
        enemy_health = 9.5
    else:
        enemy_health = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `wave` variable is an integer, this is simple<sup>1</sup>. If it is not, you should be able to cast it to an int for the same effect. Making it an input to the function makes this simple (since you can force the conversion).

It looks like you increase the `enemy_health` value 1.5 per 10 wave (at least until 70, where you revert to 1). So simply divide `wave` by 10 and then multiple by 1.5, and add it to an offset. You may need some special handling for base cases (`wave` <10 or >=70).

Without considering those edge cases, your function becomes

```
func add_health(current_wave: int):
    # Parentheses probably unnecessary, but useful for clarity
    enemy_health = ((current_wave/10) * 1.5) + 0.5
```

<sup>1</sup> Dividing two integers results in an integer, discarding any remainder. So 53/10 == 5

Comment: Thanks for the answer I think this can work. BTW, if it's ```59/10``` will it still be 5?

Comment: Yes. Integer division will truncate, not round. Note that this is *integer* division, where one integer divided by another integer yields an integer result. The same is not true for non-integers; so `59/10 == 5`, but `59/10.0 == 5.9` and `59.0/10 == 5.9`.

Comment: Great! I am using integers so this should be great!